# How to limit "SELECT" results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the next code and he showing new categoires im making to the users.
the problem I dont know how to limit the results and make like limit for 5 last categiroes? thanks! sorry about bad english.
thanks

```
   <?php
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM categories');
    $stmt->execute();
    echo $stmt->rowCount();
?>
</span>
</a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu extended notification">
    <li>
        <p>Categories</p>
    </li>

<?php
    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
            $html = '<li>';
            $html .= '<div class="alert alert-info clearfix">';
            $html .= '<span class="alert-icon"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></span>';
            $html .= '<div class="noti-info">';
            $html .= 'Category #'.$row['CategoryID'].' '.$row['CategoryName'].'';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</li>';

            echo $html;
        }
    } else {
        $html = '<li>';
        $html .= '<div class="alert alert-danger clearfix">';
        $html .= '<span class="alert-icon"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></span>';
        $html .= '<div class="noti-info">';
        $html .= '<a href="#"> There are no available categories.</a>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</li>';

        echo $html;
    }
?>
```

Comment: ORDER BY someid DESC LIMIT 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html), [DESC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html) and [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html) on your query, i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY ColumnNameEx DESC LIMIT 5;
```

---

> `ORDER BY`
>
> In some cases, `MySQL` can use an index to satisfy an `ORDER BY` clause
>   without doing extra sorting.
>   The index can also be used even if the `ORDER BY` does not match the
>   index exactly, as long as all unused portions of the index and all
>   extra `ORDER BY` columns are constants in the `WHERE` clause

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

---

> `DESC`
>
> The default sort order is ascending, with smallest values first. To
>   sort in reverse (descending) order, add the `DESC` keyword to the name
>   of the column you are sorting by.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html

---

> `LIMIT`
>
> If you need only a specified number of rows from a result set, use a
>   `LIMIT` clause in the query, rather than fetching the whole result set
>   and throwing away the extra data.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html

---

Comment: He wants the last 5 not random 5

Comment: Add ORDER BY clause would be better

Answer (score 0):

Add at the end of the query "LIMIT x", x is the amount of results you want to get

Comment: +yaringroiser No. This is just a Google thing.

Comment: It's usually the polite thing to give a small example based on the person's question. Throwing them at the mercy of Google isn't very nice.